# Problem on Line 0

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm new to salesforce dev and am trying to create a simple visual force page.  I'm getting the below problem and my page is coming up blank on preview.  How do I fix this?

Name: GeneralDefense
Line: 0
Problem: Stage2.1-GeneralDefense

and here is the code

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="General Defense">
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.1-GeneralDefense">Is the personal Information required by the business in order to comply with federal, state or local laws?</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.2-GeneralDefense">Is the personal information required by the business in order to comply with a civil, criminal, or regulatory inquiry, investigation, subpoena, or summons by federal, state, or local authorities?</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.3-GeneralDefense">Is the personal information required by the business in order to cooperate with law enforcement agencies concerning conduct or activity that the business, service provider, or third party reasonably and in good faith believes may violate federal, state, or local law?</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.4-GeneralDefense">Is the personal information required by the business needed in order to exercise or defend legal claims?</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.5-GeneralDefense">Does the business collect, use, retain, sell or disclose consumer information that is de-identified or in the aggregate as it relates to the information being requested?</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.6-GeneralDefense">Does every aspect of commercial conduct take place wholly outside of California?</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.7-GeneralDefense">Is the personal information medical information governed by the Confidentiality of Medical Information Act (Part 2.6 (commencing with Section 56 of Division 1) or protected health information that is collected by a covered entity or business associate governed by the privacy, security, and breach notification rules issued by the United States Department of Health and Human Services, Parts 160 and 164 of Title 45 of the Code of Federal Regulations, established pursuant to the Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act of 1996 (Public Law 104-191) and the Health Information Technology for Economic and Clinical Health Act (Public Law 111-5)?</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.8-GeneralDefense"></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.9-GeneralDefense"></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.10-GeneralDefense"></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.11-GeneralDefense"></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.12-GeneralDefense"></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.13-GeneralDefense"></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.14-GeneralDefense"></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.15-GeneralDefense"></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Stage2.16-GeneralDefense"></label>
            </p>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.1-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.2-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.3-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.4-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.5-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.6-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.7-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.8-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.9-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.10-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.11-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.12-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.13-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.14-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.15-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>
            <p>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="Stage2.16-GeneralDefense"></apex:inputCheckbox>
            </p>            
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <!--6 HelpText="For purposes of this question, commercial conduct takes place wholly outside of California if the business collected that information while the consumer was outside of California, no part of the sale of the consumer’s personal information occurred in California, and no personal information collected while the consumer was in California is sold.  This paragraph shall not permit a business from storing, including on a device, personal information about a consumer when the consumer is in California and then collecting that personal information when the consumer and stored personal information is outside of California"-->
    <!--7 HelpText="For purposes of this subdivision, the definitions of “medical information” and “provider of health care” in Section 56.05 shall apply and the definitions of “business associate,” “covered entity,” and “protected health information” in Section 160.103 of Title 45 of the Code of Federal Regulations shall apply."-->
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

It was the periods in the inputCheckbox id's.  After removal and replace with - it worked like a dream